# UIView subclass: star-shaped button in a table view doesn't react accordingly when touched

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7

Hello, everyone. I'm trying to make a star-shaped button that, when you click on it, it changes from an empty star to a filled one, and vice versa. This star gets included in a table view, so each individual cell has a star at the rightmost side.

The problem is that when I run the simulator, the empty star shows up all fine, but I can't make it change shape to a filled one. I browsed all over the web but I can't find a solution to what's causing the problem.

I included the UIView subclass I made to design the star-shaped button.

Also, this is my first time using stackoverflow, so if there is a better way to phrase the question, or a better way to receive help, please tell me.

Thank you all in advance.

```
import UIKit

class StarFilling: UIView {

//MARK: Properties
var marking = 0{
    didSet {
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
var starList = [UIButton]()

// MARK: Initialization

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33, height: 33))

    button.addTarget(self, action: "fillingStar", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

    addSubview(button)
}

// MARK: Button Action
func fillingStar(button: UIButton){
    if(marking == 0){
        marking = 1
    }
    else{
        marking = 0
    }
    updateButtonSelectionStates()
}

func updateButtonSelectionStates(){
    if(marking==1){
        for button in starList{
            button.selected = true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override touchesBegan and pointInside in order for your subviews, your star button, to receive the events. You can also use the selected member variable of UIButton to toggle the state.

```
class StarFilling: UIView {

  override init (frame : CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    initStar()
  }

  convenience init ()
  {
    self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)

  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initStar()
  }

  func initStar()
  {
    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "star_filled")
    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "star_empty")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 100, width: 100, height: 60))

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StarFilling.fillingStar(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)

    addSubview(button)
  }
  // MARK: Button Action
  func fillingStar(sender : UIButton)
  {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
  {
    for view in subviews
    {
      view.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
  }

  override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }
}
```

In your ViewController:

```
let star = StarFilling()
star.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(star)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice! Really appreciate the effort you put into this.

Comment: The only problem is, now XCode throws Thread1: Signal SIGABRT error.
I checked all the outlets and did what I could from the internet, but unfortunately the error continues.

Do you have any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: Solved it! Thanks for your code :). Everything's working fine now. I'm finally so relieved.